# Do you still need to dispose attachments in .net v4 System.Net.Mail?

Tags: .net, mailing

With .net v3.5 or less it was required to manually dispose attachments after sending an email using SMTP client, is this still required in .net v4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN, the [Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144637(VS.100).aspx) method still exists in .net 4, and the notes still say you should call it, so I would assume nothing has changed.

- [.Net 3.5 AttachmentBase.Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144637(VS.90).aspx)
- [.Net 4 AttachmentBase.Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144637(VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The class is IDisposable and the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) still calls Dispose on it.